# MongoDb query sharded collection with $in

Tags: mongodb-query, mongo-java-driver

I have a sharded collection with the shard key on the _id and company fields. 
So a document would look like:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e69a25624aa9a09d6a9e684"),
  "company": "ABC",
  "name": "Joe",
  "address": "123 street"
},
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5e69a25624aa9a09d6a9e683"),
  "company": 4,
  "name": "Fred",
  "address": "123 street"
},
```

Some of the company fields are numeric ids and some are strings. 
I want to write a query like this:
`db.people.findAndModify({"query": {"_id": ObjectId("5e69a25624aa9a09d6a9e684"), "company": {"$in": ["ABC", "4", 4]}}, "update": {"$set": {"address": "433 street"}}})`

The reason some are strings and some are numbers is because the legacy format for the company id was a number but with recent changes it could also be a string. Also, at query time, I don't know which format I need to use.

The above query fails with an error like this

```
QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: Error: findAndModifyFailed failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Query for sharded findAndModify must contain the shard key",
        "code" : 61,
        "codeName" : "ShardKeyNotFound",
        "$clusterTime" : {
                "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1584461817, 1),
                "signature" : {
                        "hash" : BinData(0,"ud27faacC2Jn3bYt1w0MNMr2MD0="),
                        "keyId" : NumberLong("6785743810203746305")
                }
        },
        "operationTime" : Timestamp(1584461817, 1)
}
```

I'm using the java mongo driver which appears to force me to use the `findAndModify` function.

How can I query the collection using `$in` on the company field?
I can see when I write queries on the command line that if I use `updateMany` or `updateOne` things work fine, is there any way to get the java mongo driver to use one of those methods instead of `findAndModify`?

Answer (score 0):

After posting this I toyed around some more and found that I could change my java code from

`metaDataCollection.updateMany(query, set, options);`

to

`metaDataCollection.bulkWrite(Arrays.asList(new UpdateManyModel<>(query, set, options)));`

Which appears to have solved the problem.